# Java await function - concurrent programming

Tags: java

I have non-blocking method `start()` which makes two separate calls and combines results together when they back as `future.OnSuccess() {...}.`

I want to implement a function which would block a thread wait for a results and release it as soon as both sub results are ready.

Example:

```
MyJob job = new MyJob();
job.start();
job.awaitResults();
Result rs = job.getResult();
```

Could you please recommend the best way achieving that?

Comment: could you not just use a thread and then use join() instead of awaitResults()?  For example have MyJob implement Runable then instantiate a Thread t = new Thread(job) then do t.join() where you have job.awaitResults()?

Comment: @DanMatthews-Grout, thanks for reply Dan, could you please be more specific, your answer sounds reasonable but I am not sure if I understood it completely.

Comment: Post the code for MyJob and then I'll post the answer.